# Converting mixed data set to numerical data set

Tags: data-mining

In my project i have to work with mixed dataset (i.e.it has both categorical and numerical data). Is there any algorithm or method for converting categorical values to numerical values so finally my dataset should contain only numerical values. Can anyone please help me out....
(Im doing my project in matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Use one-hot encoding.

But don't expect the results to be very good. There is a lot of meaning lost this way.

Comment: my project objective is to provide good results.....,im googling bt I didnt find   related one...,